# Can the US Government require registration to obtain government-developed code?

Tags: law, floss

I've *heard* that it is against US Government policy to require registration in order to download US Government-developed Open Source code.  But I couldn't find definitive answer via 15 minutes of internet search.

Does anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 4):

US Government-written code is by law public domain and not subject to copyright; however, like any government document it isn't necessarily publicly releasable.  Various restrictions exist, such as DoD-only, government-only, government-and-contractors only, US nationals only, export controlled information, etc., and such restrictions can be managed by requiring registration.